# Toolbar item misplaced after upgrading eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna, eclipse-project-file

I had some plugins which was developed in Eclipse Indigo (3.7).
Now i wanted to update my Eclipse to Luna (4.4.2).
After some clearing issues, I got my product.
But now the problem is menu bar item are misplaced.
In the below image I have shown how exactly tool bar looks if I built in Indigo and Luna.

[image]

Please tell me what went wrong and what should I do to correct that

Comment: Exactly what about this supposed to be wrong? It just likes the extra tool bar items in Luna have forced the bar on to two lines.

Comment: Two lines is nor a problem, please check the item which are there.<br\>they are miss placed